# sending form with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I want to create a function to handle form submission.

Ideally it would work like this:

1. checks form for any anchor tags with a class="error".
2. If it exists then do nothing.
3. Else then perform the form action and method(method=post action="file.php").
4. slideUp containing div
5. Delay 2 seconds
6. fade in div id="form success message"

I am not that strong with if statements yet and could use some guidance.

Comment: My suggestion would be to start with a tutorial of sorts, then go through the official documentation and read about the functions that were used. People here aren't going to just write your code for you.

Comment: "plz send teh codes" type questions are not acceptable here.  As Dave said, google and follow tutorials, there's a lot out there.

Comment: @Dave I did not expect anyone to. I was looking for some help, not the answer.

I've read through the documentation and can set up an if statement to do alerts and minor things like that. I have no problem showing and hiding and delaying. More or less just looking for some help about how to get jQuery to perform the form actions...

I know about .sumbit but dont know how to link it to the html method and action.

Comment: "Not that strong with if statements" is not compatible with this set of requirements!

Comment: @patrick http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: you'll never learn anything if you don't try to write a line of code but just ask for complete solutions. Don't be lazy.

Comment: Thanks above for taking the time to try to motivate me. The fact is I've spent 3 hours thismorning wrestling with if statements, and reading jQuery documentation & tutorials to sort out how to do this. I'm not lazy or looking for a hand out, just some guidance as specified in my post. 

I get that it must be frustrating that people post on here expecting someone else to do their work, but that is not the case. I have a genuine interest in wanting to understand and write jQuery fluently.

Someday when Im a pro, I'll remember patience and reciprocate the love shared to me here.

Comment: @patrick With all due respect, this stuff doesn't take 3 hours to learn. That's usually why people just don't offer their time up to blatantly write code for others. When you show you are making the earnest effort, you will receive the most assistance. Nobody here is hating on you!

Comment: @Dave, must be how I phrased the question that made it seem I was looking for a handout. Bottom line is I'm just not a strong objective programmer, and it does take time for someone like me to wrap my head around an entire unfamiliar library, especially when I fumble over syntax errors.

Comment: @patrick Yeah, if you can make your questions a little less broad you'll get much more support.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for your patience, and I'll remember. P.S. You'd be surprised how much I've learned on here with help from people like you, or maybe you wouldn't based on your reputation. Either way, I don't think anyone is hating on me, this value of this community is undefinable. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but should give you direction.

```
<form method="post" action="file.php" target="iframe">
...
</form>

<iframe src="about:blank" name="iframe" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<div id="form_success_message" style="display: none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("form").submit(function() {
    if ($("a.error", this).length > 0)
        return;
    $(this).parent().slideUp("2000", function() {
        $("#form_success_message").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks dtbarne! This should be enough to get me going. A little help goes a long way. Cheers.

Comment: I guess I don't really need to handle the form submission with the jQuery because it sumbit button should do that on it's own. 

Using .length to check for the a.error was really what I needed. 
Cheers.